Error in compiling Variable Infiltration Capacity Model on MacOSx
I have been trying to compile Variable Infiltration Capacity (VIC) model, it is a land surface model developed by the University of Washington (https://vic.readthedocs.io/en/master/). The version of VIC that I am using is VIC.5.0.0 and the image driver version of the model.
Name and version of the C compiler I am using:

Apple clang version 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.3). The operating system is MacOSx Sequoia (15.0.1).

The dependencies needed for the installation are:

NECTDF Version: netcdf 4.9.2
OPEN-MPI Version: open-mpi 5.0.5

I tried the classic version and it was compiled successfully but need to install the image driver to support MPI functionality and NETCDF support. But when I am trying to run "make" in the image driver, I get the following error:
ld: 3 duplicate symbols
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [model] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
duplicate symbols:
duplicate symbol '_vic_run_ref_str' in:
/private/var/folders/pr/c0c0wd3x0cjbdx4rzvgl384c0000gq/T/CalcBlowingSnow-6cd169.o
duplicate symbol '_LOG_DEST' in:
/private/var/folders/pr/c0c0wd3x0cjbdx4rzvgl384c0000gq/T/CalcBlowingSnow-6cd169.o
duplicate symbol '_funcd' in:
/private/var/folders/pr/c0c0wd3x0cjbdx4rzvgl384c0000gq/T/CalcBlowingSnow-6cd169.o
I understand that it is a problem with ld with a clang. Any possible solution or workaround regarding this error?
Thanks in advance.
